# Convert the column values from a set in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have received a table as shown here. I see only one row:

| Column1 | Column2 | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [1,2,3,4,5] | [6,7,8,9,10] | ["2018-03-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-05-01", "2018-06-01", "2018-07-01"] |

I would like to see the data like this:

| time | Column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-03-01 | 1 | 6 |
| 2018-04-01 | 2 | 7 |
| 2018-05-01 | 3 | 8 |
| 2018-06-01 | 4 | 9 |
| 2018-07-01 | 5 | 10 |

My table consists of **15** columns and about 1900 values of set.

How can I solve this problem?

I tried `STRING_AGG` but I don't want to write all columns name.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how string_agg would help you here even if you wrote all columns names.

Comment: it was just an idea.  How else can I solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

```sql
with data as (
  select *
  from (values
    ('[1,2,3,4,5]', '[6,7,8,9,10]', '["2018-03-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-05-01", "2018-06-01", "2018-07-01"]')
  ) v(Column1, Column2, time)
)
select
  t.[value],
  c1.[value] as Column1,
  c2.[value] as Column2
from
  (select [key], [value] from data cross apply openjson(data.time)) t
  inner join (select [key], [value] from data cross apply openjson(data.Column1)) c1 on t.[key] = c1.[key]
  inner join (select [key], [value] from data cross apply openjson(data.Column2)) c2 on t.[key] = c2.[key]
;
```

Comment: I can not write all values. I have about 1900 values.

Comment: No, you don't. You have 15 columns. Write them all.